# Book that copies(?) MythologySE

Tags: discussion

While recently searching for myself online (Admit it, you've all done that at least once), I saw something I didn't expect.

A book result.

Opening it, I saw it. It was a copy of a question I answered here on Mythology.SE. And not only that, it was composed solely of questions from Mythology.SE.

[Mythology - Questions and Answers](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=zDhLDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT906&lpg=PT906&dq=MalayTheDynamo&source=bl&ots=UnzNwPxJn3&sig=rrQdljA8APVzKh9aI2Vxs8Aqga4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjWmfGSkLTZAhUBHZQKHfRYDCoQ6AEwFHoECCUQAQ#v=onepage&q=MalayTheDynamo&f=false) by George A. Duckett

What should we do?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'm uncomfortable with the very low quality (and extreme prices) of [George Duckett's books](https://www.amazon.com/George-Duckett/e/B00M87SQR2). However, content on Stack Exchange sites is licensed under the [Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/us/) and as long as the books properly follow its attribution requirements there isn't anything we can - or should - do.

A little bit more detail on the network Meta:

- [Are these eBooks that copy from SE illegal?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273989/162704)
- [Proper attribution of Stack Exchange content in a printed publication](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288561/proper-attribution-of-stack-exchange-content-in-a-printed-publication)

Comment: Does it attribute? I didn't see any attributions.

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo You don't? Isn't the text "answer by malaythedynamo" the reason you discovered the book in the first place?

Comment: That counts as an attribution? Guess it does....

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo IANAL but I think it does.

Comment: I tried looking myself up, by all I got was some guy who has been dead for centuries(210 years).

Comment: @AndrewJohnson Probably the "book" was put together before you started contributing to the site. I am not sure if George Duckett updates the "books", but if he does I'm sure you'll appear in one of them soon enough.

Comment: I've only been here fur 4 months, so I would have to agree.